# Grid Display of Screen when running python file using a .kv for GUI / Using Pycharm in Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, user-interface, kivy

I'm following a tutorial on youtube and when I run the code, the window shows the labels half off the screen on the left-bottom side. I uploaded a screenshot of the window.[image]

The .kv file is:

```
<MyGrid>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label:
                text: "Name: "

            TextInput:
                multiline:False

            Label:
                text: "Email: "

            TextInput:
                multiline:False

        Button:
            text: "Submit"
```

And the py file is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MyGrid(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp (App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Try inheriting `MyGrid` from a `Layout` class, or set `size` of its children explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the base `Widget` class as a container, but it was not designed for that use. Try just using some `Layout` class as the base for `MyGrid`, like this:

```
class MyGrid(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

Note that this will result in a GUI that is a `FloatLayout` that contains a `GridLayout` which contains another `GridLayout`. If that is not your intention, consider changing the base class of `MyGrid` to `GridLayout` and eliminate one or two of the contained `GridLayouts`.